# <AG-Grid> Property 'children' does not exist on type 'ColDef<object>'

Tags: typescript, ag-grid

trying to do a project on AG grid but I am coming across an error with typescript. It says ([AG-Grid] Property 'children' does not exist on type 'ColDef') getting this error around the filter method below where (column => column.children).

I went to the documentation of ag-grid but I can see that column defs support using children as a property. So I am not sure why I am getting this error?

[image]

```
import { ColDef, ColGroupDef } from 'ag-grid-community';

export const sampleItems: Array<{
  label: string;
  value: string;
}> = [];

export const TABLE_COLUMN = [
  {
    headerName: 'User',
    children: [
      {
        field: 'user',
        headerName: 'Name',
        pinned: 'left',
        type: 'fixed',
      },
      { field: 'account', pinned: 'left', type: 'fixed' },
      {
        field: 'price',
        headerName: 'Pricing',
        pinned: 'left',
        type: 'primary',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Address',
    children: [
      { field: 'address', headerName: 'Address', type: 'secondary' },
      {
        field: 'street',
        headerName: 'Street Name',
        columnGroupShow: 'closed',
        type: 'secondary',
      },
    ],
  },
] as (ColDef<object> | ColGroupDef<object>)[];


TABLE_COLUMN.filter((column) => column.children != null).forEach(
  (column) => {
    column.children.forEach((child) => {
      if (child.type === 'fixed' || child.type === 'primary') {
        sampleItems.push({
          label:
            child.headerName ??
            child.field.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + child.field.slice(1),
          value: child.field,
        });
      }
    });
  },
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the logic to. We are telling typescript that it will be a `colGroupDef`, so it wont bother checking for `ColDef` type.

```
 (<ColGroupDef<object>>TABLE_COLUMN).filter((column: ColGroupDef<object>) => column.children != null).forEach(
  (column: ColGroupDef<object>) => {
    column.children.forEach((child: ColDef<object>) => {
      if (child.type === 'fixed' || child.type === 'primary') {
        sampleItems.push({
          label:
            child.headerName ??
            child.field.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + child.field.slice(1),
          value: child.field,
        });
      }
    });
  },
);
```

Comment: When I explicitly tell typescript it will be colGroupDef, there will then a another error on child.type because type is not a property of colGroupDef

Comment: thank you! this works for me

Sorry to ask more of you but I am new to typescript. What do you call this kind of syntax <(<ColGroupDef<object>>TABLE_COLUMN)>? Why did you put the type in front of the variable? I want to learn more about this.

I am only familiar on the colon notation. (ie. variable: type)

Comment: So our variable is having two possibilities it can be `ColDef<object> | ColGroupDef<object>` we can tell typescript, that we are certain that its of type `ColDef<object>` by wrapping them inside `<>`  try to checkout this post on [typecasting](https://www.codingninjas.com/codestudio/library/type-casting-in-typescript)